# Symfony 1.4: Programmatically set environment for CLI

Tags: php, symfony1, environment, command-line-interface

I have a project built on Symfony 1.4 and it has multiple environments - each developer has their own copy installed on their local machine and therefore has their own environment.

I am able to dynamically set the environment in index.php, but how can I do this for CLI tasks?

I could of course use --env=myenvironment on all tasks, but I would prefer it to be able to use the same logic as I have in index.php

Comment: How are you determining the environment for the developer in index.php? Host name? GET parameter? can you show us some code?

Comment: It looks for the existence of environment.cfg file in the main config directory.   The contents of this file specify the environment as a string.   The advantage is that this file is not committed to SVN, so each developer can specify their own configuration without affecting the config in svn.

Answer (score 2):

`sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->getEnvironment()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to this in your task perhaps:

```
class MyTask extends sfBaseTask
{
  protected function configure()
  {
    // Env config file
    $file = sfConfig::get("sf_config_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "environment.cfg";
    $env = (file_exists($file) ? file_get_contents($file) : "prod");

    $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', $env),
  }
}
```

The above should work; it defaults to the 'prod' environment if the environment.cfg file doesn't exist.  This also assumes that you have just the environment in the file (eg 'prod', 'dev', 'slappythefish' etc).

Comment: Thanks, this should work - but is there a global way to do it, so that when I type symfony propel:insert-sql-diff, it automatically works out which environment to use?